# How to find VS2015 build "up-to-date" cause

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How can I find out why VS2015 is returning the following, when it should instead be building?

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have my build verbosity turned all the way up (to "diagnostic"). It definitely yields very detailed build logs **when it builds**. But when it says "up-to-date" as shown above, the text above is my entire build window output.

I found mention of earlier versions of VS having a "fast up-to-date" feature, that seems like it could be causing this build-bypass sort of result. Apparently one can [troubleshoot that using the `U2DCheckVerbosity` registry flag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2014/08/04/how-to-investigate-rebuilding-in-visual-studio-when-nothing-has-changed/), but that flag doesn't seem to affect VS 2015.

Ultimately, I want to find out why VS 2015 thinks my project is up-to-date, when MSBUILD from a command line does not.

Answer (score 0):

The same flag works for vs2015 as long as you change the registry path from "12.0" to "14.0".